# how to make the position of button fixed in android?

Tags: android

I have a button and a expand list above this button , when the list is expanded the button below it disappears . how to make this button in fixed location?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<include layout="@layout/ads_bar" ></include>        
<TextView 
                android:text="Level 1:"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<TextView 
                android:text="lorem ispum something about this level ..... :)"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>

<include 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                layout="@layout/quick_links_bar"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```

where `quick_links_bar` represents button !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `quick_links_bar` layout to always stay at the bottom? You'll need to use `RelativeLayout` for that.

Wrap your whole layout in a RelativeLayout and move your quick links bar layout outside of the LinearLayout and set the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on it. For this next bit, you'll need to assign an id to your quick links bar. On your LinearLayout, set the property `android:layout_above="@id/quicklinksbarid"`. Make sure your quick links bar include statement is above the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

To acheve button aligned to the bottom it's better to use layout_weight attribute of the linear layout.

Simple example:

```
<LinearLayout>

   <TextView layout_weight=1/>
   <Button layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout>
```

This is better than using RElative layout because if using one you will have the bottom of your text cut off by the button, but in this case it will not happen.